# Eclipse error: Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, eclipse-neon

I am using Eclipse Neon. I can't run the project because of this error: "Target runtime Apache Tomcat v7.0 is not defined".

[image]

**Note 1:** This window is not available in Neon version as it is suggested in some posts: "right click on your project > Properties > Targeted Runtime > Click the version required 8.0"

**Note 2:** The content of my settings file is below (`org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <runtime name="Apache Tomcat v7.0"/>
  <fixed facet="java"/>
  <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.8"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install the JST Server adapters. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace and try looking for JST server adapters and install them.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your runtime server from 'Apache Tomcat v7.0' to V8,

Right Click on Project > Properties > Java Build Path

Click on Add Library > Click Server Runtime > Select server which is available.

Comment: In "Add Library" window, I have 4 options: "JRE System Library", "JUnit", "Maven Managed Dependencies", "User Library"

Comment: Have configured any apache server on your eclipse ?